# Angular JS animation not working, (using ngAnimate and TweenMax)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate, gsap

ok, here is my code:

```
(function(){
```

//Define angular main module - module -

```
var app = angular.module('module', ['ngAnimate']);
```

//Define controller -TimeLine-

```
app.controller('TimeLine', function(){
    this.initialize = true;
});
```

//Define controller -PersonalGravatar-

```
app.controller('PersonalGravatar', function(){
    this.email = "mail@gmail.com";
    this.getImage = function(email) {
        // MD5 (Message-Digest Algorithm) by WebToolkit
        var size = size || 460;
        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + MD5(email) + '.jpg?s=' + size;
    };
});
```

//Define animation - gravatar-

```
app.animation(".gravatar", function() {
    console.log("im displaying correctly");
    //that's it, this next 'return' is not working.
    return {
        console.log("im NOT displaying in console");
        enter: function(element, done){
            TweenMax.to(element, 2, { css:{left:500, onComplete:done} } );
        },
        leave: function(element, done){
            // TweenMax.to(element, 2, { css:{left:500, onComplete:done} } );
        }
    };
});

})();
```

then my html code is:

```
<html class="no-js" ng-app="module"> 
... more code ...
<div id="app-main-container" ng-controller="TimeLine as animations">

        <div id="gravatar" class="gravatar" ng-controller="PersonalGravatar as gravatar"
         ng-if="animations.initialize">
            <img ng-src="{{gravatar.getImage(gravatar.email)}}" alt="">
        </div>

</div> <!-- /app main container -->
<script src="../1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<cript src="../1.2.18/angular-animate.min.js"> </script>
<script src="../1.12.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

so I'm new in angularJS, I don't no why app.animation is not returning any animation.. thanks a LOT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just $timeout...

```
 app.controller('TimeLine', function($scope, $timeout){
    return $timeout(function() {
        $scope.initialize = true;
    }, 100);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Plunk of your example animating the enter and leave.

Notice how you no longer need to wrap your CSS properties in a css object.

```
enter: function(element, done){
    TweenMax.from(element, 1, {x:500, autoAlpha: 0, scale: 0.5, onComplete:done});
},
leave: function(element, done){
    TweenMax.to(element, 1, {x:500, autoAlpha: 0, scale: 0.5, onComplete:done});
}
```

*Plunker* http://plnkr.co/edit/6tQFdA?p=preview